# What is the equivalent of an allocation from C++ in C

Tags: c

I have the following kind of source code in C++. Now I want to make this program in C too (with C++ compiler) but I am confused about allocation.

My current code of my function

```
char* product(char* a, unsigned short b, unsigned short zeroes)
{

char* finish = new char[strlen(a) + 2 + zeroes]();
short carry = 0;
unsigned short c;
unsigned short s;

for (short i = strlen(a) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    c = char2int(a[i]);
    s = (b*c + carry);
    carry = s / 10;
    finish[strlen(finish)] = int2char(s % 10);
}

printf("%s", finish); // dump! Looking what is inside

if (carry > 0) {
    finish[strlen(finish)] = int2char(carry);
}

reverseChar(finish);

for (short i = 0; i < zeroes; i++) {
    finish[strlen(finish)] = '0';
}

return ltrim(finish,'0'); // trim
}
```

I've tried to allocate via `malloc.h` using this `(char*) malloc (strlen(a) + 2 + zeroes)` but it gave me random chars (at the dump part). Is someone possible to say me what just happend here?

Comment: "program in C too (with C++ compiler) " - does make your program a C++ program! Do not use a C++ compiler to compile C code! As much as you woul dnot use a Java compiler to compile C++ source. C and C++ are **different** languages.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! (This is one of the differences)

Comment: "I want to make this program in C too (with C++ compiler)" is confusing.  Do you want the **same exact** user source code to be compilable with C++ and C?  Or are you porting the C++ code to C that can have different source but same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator new` allocates memory, but also calls the constructors of the objects to be created.

In this case `char()` which initializes them to zero.

To have equvalent code you could for example use `memset`.

Note that if your type is not of size one (like char), you also have to multiply the amount you give to malloc by the size of the type. `new` does this automatically.

The actual issue with your code starts when you call `strlen(finish)` when there is garbage in the memory.

Comment: `calloc` would also achieve this same result.

Comment: `char* finish = ( char* ) calloc ( 1 ,  size );` works fine for this situation. Thankk